# Some calculations in pandas with the addition of a column

Tags: python, csv, pandas, row

I have a table that has a column "Col1" that looks something like this:

| Col1 |

|    2 |

|    2 |

|    4 |

|    4 |

|    4 |

|    4 |

|    3 |

|    3 |

|    3 |

|    3 |

|    3 |

|    3 |

I need to create a new column "Col2". The table after this should look like this:

| Col1 | Col2 |

|    2 |    1 |

|    2 |    2 |

|    4 |    1 |

|    4 |    2 |

|    4 |    3 |

|    4 |    4 |

|    3 |    1 |

|    3 |    2 |

|    3 |    3 |

|    3 |    1 |

|    3 |    2 |

|    3 |    3 |

Is it possible to make so that if I have the same values in a row, the code starts from 1? As for example with 3.

|    3 |    1 |

|    3 |    2 |

|    3 |    3 |

|    3 |    1 |

|    3 |    2 |

|    3 |    3 |

Comment: Why last values are not `3-4`, `3-5`, `3-6`?

Comment: He reached 3, so you start from 1.

Comment: If the column contains 3, then it should count in the second column from 1 to 3, if, for example, 4, then from 1 to 4, and so on. In the first column 3  is repeated three times, for 4 four lines are allocated and so on. This is the difficulty for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this pandas solution without looping:

```
df2 = df.assign(Col2=df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].cumcount().mod(df['Col1']).add(1))
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
    Col1  Col2
0      2     1
1      2     2
2      4     1
3      4     2
4      4     3
5      4     4
6      3     1
7      3     2
8      3     3
9      3     1
10     3     2
11     3     3
```

Comment: Oops.  I forgot the assign.  Thanks! @jezrael

Comment: very nice and neat answer!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[2,2,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3]})
i = 0
Col2 = []
Col1 = df.Col1

#Construct Col2 
while i < (len(Col1)):
    Col2.extend(list(range(1,Col1[i]+1)))
    i = len(Col2)
#Add Col2 to Dataframe
df['Col2'] = Col2
```